# How to know when CloseThreadPool() function completes?

Tags: multithreading

i am new to Sockets programming and going through the Documentation.

From a documentation i found about CloseThreadPool() function :

CloseThreadpool function. The thread pool is closed immediately if there are no outstanding callback objects that are bound to the thread pool. If there are, then the thread pool is released asynchronously when those outstanding objects are freed.

This thread pool is in a thread itself. my main thread takes input for exit. if exit is inputted i set global variable KEEP_LISTENEING to false.

How would i wait my main thread to stop/sleep untill this function truly completes in another thread ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a cleanup group to [wait for all callbacks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/harip/archive/2010/10/11/introduction-to-the-windows-threadpool-part-1.aspx). The sequence is:

1. CreateThreadpoolCleanupGroup()
2. SetThreadpoolCallbackCleanupGroup(&CallbackEnvironment, pointerCleanup, ...)
3. CloseThreadpoolCleanupGroupMembers(, FALSE, )
4. CloseThreadpoolCleanupGroup()